# Why am I getting notifications for edits I can't review?

Tags: bug

[image]

I have 13 notifications for some edits I can't review (I guess they are tag wikis edits I made), but why am I getting the notifications if I can't review them?

Comment: This could be a bug, but are you sure it's not just the number of edits that you have in the queue? Do other people's pending edits show up for you, or your edits show up for them?

Comment: Other peoples' edits show up for me. But when I click on the notification, I can review them. Not like above, where nothing shows up

Comment: Those notifications that I posted above *are* seen by someone, cos someone accepts them

Comment: Hmm... any possibility this is related to your recently achieving 1.5K? That's the limit where you are able to make unreviewed tag wiki edits.

Comment: unreviewed wiki tags I can make at 4k reputation,if I'm not mistaken. At 1.5k (which I recently reached) I can review other peoples' suggested wiki tags, but mine have to be reviewed by somebody else

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this on other sites.  (I don't have enough rep here to see them.)  The pending-edit and flag counts are global values, not computed per-person, so everybody sees the same number, even if you can't do anything about some of them.

This is frustrating because the only way to know if there's anything for you to do is to click through and look.  But it's how the engine works, and it's not specific to this site.