# Faulty "suggested edit" notification

Tags: support, status-bydesign

On the main site, I have a notification for 1 suggested edit. However, clicking on this notification shows that there aren't actually any edits awaiting review. Furthermore, there aren't *any* kind of review tasks pending.

[Why am I getting notifications for edits I can't review?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/648/why-am-i-getting-notifications-for-edits-i-cant-review) is similar, but the answer was not accepted. Furthermore, this individual (at the time) didn't have access to all of the review tasks, which may have caused the problem. I do have access to them, yet the error is still there.

This notification has been present for at least a day now. Hovering over it shows text that says "~1 suggested edit pending approval."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the same issue Monica mentioned. There is a [meta.se post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/154443) on this - basically it is all the outstanding review items, not necessarily the ones you can action. It includes reviews you skipped etc.